# Microsoft SQL Server - sequence spring boot

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, entitymanager

I have created a sequence in SQL which works fine when executing the query in SQL Server.

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [ORDERS].SEQ_NAME

result will be for example 1000

I need to get this sequence in my spring boot service, without having an Entity so I've tried the following :

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public int getNumber(){
        return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [ORDERS].SEQ_NAME").getFirstResult();
    }
```

I've tried to add also @Transactional, i've tried various methods like getSingleResult.toString(), getResultList.get(0).toString() etc but without any luck.

Always I will get org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

I've tried this method for a select from a normal table and it works fine, the problem is only when i am interrogating from Sequences.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: To be clear, sequence is created, the connection to database is good, as an user i have access to get the sequence

Comment: I doubt it's the issue but your result set has no column name. Have you tried something like `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [ORDERS].SEQ_NAME as Foo`?

Comment: tried it. is giving Invalid object name '[ORDERS].SEQ_NAME'

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

changed the dialect from the application.properties : was SQLServerDialect and changed to SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).